# Navigate from a view model in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to push a view in xamrian forms from the view model but I cant appear to get it to work its really when the user has entered correct username and password it should show the home page.

You will see I have the on submit command this is just mock data at present so dont mind the design of code at this stage will change.

Usually I would use

```
var stocktakepage = new StockTake();         
await Navigation.PushAsync(stocktakepage);
```

But the model does not no about the navigation stack in the class is their another way to navigate from the view model thanks.

```
public  class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Action DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private string email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set
        {
            email = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Email"));
        }
    }
    private string password;
    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Password"));
        }
    }
    public ICommand SubmitCommand { protected set; get; }
    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        SubmitCommand = new Command(OnSubmit);
    }
    public void OnSubmit()
    {
        if (email != "handheld1" || password != "test123")
        {
            DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt();
        }else

        {




        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21822/call-navigation-pushasync-from-viewmodel But also on my main login page i have this. What this does is act like a delegate and allows you to push the view from the original calling page.

```
    public Login()
    {
         var vm = new LoginViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = vm;

Password.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
     vm.SubmitCommand.Execute(null);


  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below in order to Navigate from your `ViewModel`. You can do this for each type of page you want. Check below examples:

```
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new PageName());
```

also

```
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new PageName()) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#101010"), BarTextColor = Color.White, }, true);
```